# Acces Query : check last three number

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Good evening to everyone , i'm just doing an access's query.
I'm searching all the row , who ends with three number .
An example are those three rows :

```
bhjefhbhhe002
allfrit001
de1dhrc
```

I don't know to do , I was thinking about regex but access doesn't support regex.
Looking for someone who can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support regex but it does extend [`LIKE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) to have very limited regular expression functionality.  So you can do:

```
where col like "*[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS Access the wildcard that represents a numeric digit is `#`:

```
WHERE col LIKE '*###'
```